# Storing results of a sql query into a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am really new at SQL and PHP. Basically I need to store a query result into a variable. I have something like this:

```
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = ($user)");
```

So I want `$id` to have the value of id from table `users` where the `name` field in `users table = $user` (value of a logged-in user).

May I know how to make this work?

Comment: Yo can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157905/mysql-query-result-in-php-variable

Comment: In this ase your first step should have been to check the php.net's mysql tutorial http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` only execute the query. you can not get the results from this.
you need `mysql_fetch_assoc` for fetching the records.
and you should put `$user` in quotes.

check the below code.

```
$id= mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = '$user'");

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($id)){
   print_r($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

user mysql_fecth_object: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php

```
$query= mysql_query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = '"'. mysql_real_escape_string($user) .'"' LIMIT 1);

$result = mysql_fetch_object($query); 
$id = $result->id;
```

This extension was deprecated in `PHP 5.5.0`, and it was removed in `PHP 7.0.0`. You should use `MySli or PDO` instead

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing `mysq_query()` .you will get a complete data table towards your query.just check one way to find the solution is given below.

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name = '$user'");
if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $id=$row['id'];
}
```