# Setting Value of variable from query

Tags: php, variables

Hi anyone know how to get the `TID`. I only need the `TID` and set it to variable `$TID`

```
$sql = 'SELECT TID FROM  walkin ORDER BY TID DESC LIMIT 1';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($conn->error) {
    die("Query failed: " . $conn->error);
}
$TID = /answer here/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql query result in php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157905/mysql-query-result-in-php-variable)

Comment: Have you checked the [**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)? And have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe `fetch` it.  Wherever you saw `query` and `error` they didn't show an example of fetching?

Answer (score 0):

How about a prepared statement with a `bind_result` and `fetch` call?

```
if($stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT TID FROM walkin ORDER BY TID DESC LIMIT 1")){
    if($stmt->execute() && $stmt->bind_result($TID) && $stmt->fetch()){
        echo $TID;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Isaiah Did my answer solve your problem?  If so, please award the green tick to my answer.  If not, please leave me a comment describing what has gone wrong for you while implementing.